# How to change naming convention inspection of PEP 8 in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, pep8

I installed PyCharm-2019 and enabled PEP8 checks in Inspections. It's a good idea that helps us to write a beautiful code. But I have a little problem with that.

If I write something like that:

```
def BuildDataset(_direction):
    print("Something")
```

the IDE shows me this warning: 'Argument name should be lowercase ...'.
The IDE's telling me you should write your code as like as my type naming convention. But I like to write my code as my naming convention. For instance, I'm interested to write a function using a capital letter in fist of each word and after that join them together, like 'BuildDataset'. Or something like that.
Is there a way to change PyCharm naming convention?

Comment: Just disable PEP 8 checks if you are going to ignore them

Comment: Not sure what you are after. If you don't want to follow PEP-8, turn off that inspection. If you do want to follow it, name your functions lowercase.

Comment: Thank you. Can I make a new naming convention?

Comment: There is nothing like a one-person convention.